# Wordpress: prevent navigating to files in content folder unless logged in

Tags: wordpress, data-protection

So I'm working with an installation, and have files in my wp-content/uploads folder. I want to prevent people from navigating to it directly, or accessing it at all (including videos called in a podcast), unless they are logged into the site.

It this a simple htaccess thing? I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Good and important question. This will probably be possible only by using a PHP script as a "gateway" to check whether the user is logged in, and pass through the file using `fread()`. That is not perfect for performance, especially not when serving video, but probably your only choice. I'm sure there are WP plugins for this

Comment: I've looked into plugins for "members only" functions, and a lot of them come with extra bloat... it seems like this might be something that WP would have to handle, but I figured it was worth asking about just in case there was something simple and streamlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin to handle this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-files/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Options All -Indexes
```

to your .htaccess file after the *# END WordPress* line.

It will prevent people from browsing your folders and display a forbidden message if they try. See:
http://catrabbit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/

---

I misinterpreted the question. Sorry.

To clarify:
This stops *everyone* (logged in or otherwise) from browsing your folders. I'm not sure why do want to allow logged in users to browse the uploads folder in the first place...